# Could multiple navigation sections with the same links hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, links, navigation, markup

I'm working with a site design that calls for two distinct headers and accompanying sets of navigation; however, the nav links within both are identical. I have one header with the `id` "main" containing a "primary" `nav`; I also have a fixed header that reveals via jQuery when the user scrolls beneath the primary navigation; this fixed navigation is within a `header` with the id "fixed" containing a `nav` with the id "fixed-nav."

My question, therefore, is whether effectively doubling the navigation element in this way would have an adverse effect on SEO? Also, would it matter at all how the `header`/`nav` elements are placed within the markup? For example, the placement of the fixed header could be at the very bottom of the page, given that it's positioned absolutely; however, I currently have both headers placed in a row, one after the other, at the top just under the opening `body` tag.

Comment: Okay, you explained things really well. Not too many questions are this clear. But what escapes me is why the two navigational units. Can you explain the motivation/concept more so that we understand?

Comment: Yes definitely, happy to provide clarification-- the primary reason is that both forms of navigation are very different structurally, and note that this is only an issue on the homepage. Basically, the client wants the nav links initially displayed in the form of a "business card" placed at the upper-right on the homepage; and when the user scrolls past this initial set of links, a fixed nav bar will slide down revealing the same links above for easy access. I suppose the same links could be injected via jQuery or something along those lines, but this is the general concept.

Comment: I knew there was a good reason. I am thinking on this a bit. Not sure that there would be much of any SEO effect positive or negative. Just know that Google generally excepts the first link on a page so these would have to be tuned for SEO first. Also, Google is doing all the new rendering work to analyze how a site is seen by a user. It might get confused somewhere along the line, but sometimes you just have to try things to see what happens.

Comment: Hm ok, thanks. Maybe it would be wise to place the fixed header at the bottom of the page, as I'd prefer for Google to see the "primary" links as just that; is there any reason to think that Google's algorithm takes into account the ID names assigned to elements?

Comment: You know what? That is a good question, but I do not think so. It maybe that they will get smarter about checking code, but I cannot remember seeing anything along these lines. Based on what you described, it sounds like you are okay, but perhaps someone will know more. I tend to be rather old school and only experiment around from time to time. I do know SEO fairly well and I have been at it a long time. I am semi-retired and only do research to support others and fiddle around the edges for fun. I could not leave IT entirely! I am a weird sort of a geek that way.

Comment: I have a fair amount of experience with SEO myself, although I realize the landscape is constantly changing. I can't imagine it would pose an issue in the way of duplicate content, my concern would be more along the lines of the algorithm questioning usability given that the primary nav links are included twice. However, in the age of mobile/responsive design, I would think this sort of thing is becoming more common, e.g. mobile menus that are hidden for larger screens and displayed only at certain viewports...

Comment: I agree completely. Responsive design is changing the rules a bit which benefits Google so they cannot scream too much can they?? I suspect you are okay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having a duplicate set of navigation links isn't going to change how Google sees your site much. In fact, when Googlebot encounters a second link to the same destination in a page, it generally ignores it:

- PageRank is only passed to the first link
- Anchor text only counts for the first link

Having duplicate navigation is very common.  I've worked with sites that do so for several reasons:

- Left column navigation and duplicate header navigation:  in testing they found that users prefered the left column navigation once they were familiar with the site but that new users often couldn't find it and noticed the header navigation more
- Navigation in a menu and in the footer: Navigation in a drop down menu can't be found with <kbd>ctrl-f</kbd> search, so it was duplicated in the footer for those users.

Because providing duplicate navigation can help usability and because so many sites do it, Google isn't going to have any problems with it.

The only caveat that I would add is that it might be tempting to add `rel=nofollow` to the links in one of your two navigation sections so that Googlebot pays attention to the other.  **Don't do that.**  If one set of links has nofollow, Googlebot treats both sets of links as if they had nofollow.  Google's logic is: "If the link can't be trusted in one place, why should it be trusted in another?"

Comment: **How does Google handle nofollowed links?**
In general, we don't follow them. This means that Google does not transfer PageRank or anchor text across these links. Essentially, using nofollow causes us to drop the target links from our overall graph of the web. However, the target pages may still appear in our index if other sites link to them without using nofollow, or if the URLs are submitted to Google in a Sitemap... Source: [support.google.com: Use rel="nofollow" for specific links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en)

Comment: Where can I found the proof that "PageRank is only passed to the first link"?

Comment: @DejanDozet I implemented an experiment to measure that about 10 years ago.   I created two chains of new pages.  One chain had single links to each page, the other chain double links.  After some months, I measured Googlebot's crawl rate of the pages in each chain because that is based on PageRank.  If the chain with duplicate links passed PageRank, Googlebot would re-crawl the pages in that chain more often.  However, the re-crawl rates of the pages in each chain were identical.

Comment: Thanks. I was just reading: https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/optimize-website-navigation/ part "First Link Priority – Do Multiple Links From One Page To Another Count?". The guy over there states the same as you. That the first link matters the most, but for me, that is not logical, funny, and hard to believe Anyway I accept that everything is possible even this too. So let's make the first links the best, so we don't have to think too much.